# What does this say?

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy

[image: calligraphy]

Just the kanji written out is fine, I can probably figure out what it means on my own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to belong on Chinese.SE. (EDIT: I mean migrate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says

> 廣東名畫家選集

廣東 being the Chinese prefecture Guangdong.

Comment: This may belong on Chinese.SE...?